# Захват utm меток

Tags: php, javascript, инспекция-кода

Вот сделал чтоб отправлялись utm метки вместе с формой

```
<input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_source'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_medium'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_campaign'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="utm_term" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_term'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="utm_content" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_content'];?>">
```

Скажите правильно ли? и можно ли это на js сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

лучше так

```
<input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_source']) ? $_GET['utm_source'] : '' ;?>">
```

В вашем коде если не будет гет запросов - выбьет ошибку Undefined index utm_source и т.д.

Comment: спасибо большое, вроде не было ошибок, но поставлю как вы советуете

Comment: @Александр Дахно, не могло быть ошибок в 2 случаях. 1 - вы все время передавали гет параметры. 2 - у вас не был включен вывод ошибок error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: понятно, спасибо большое.

Comment: вообще тут у вас готовый XSS — перед выводом экранировать надо всё, что приходит из `$_GET` (и вообще от пользователя)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, неправильно.

```
<input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_source'];?>">
```

Представь, что в `utm_source` окажется строка

```
1"><script>alert('Cracked!')</script><input value="
```

В итоге получится такой код

```html
<input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="1"><script>alert('Cracked!')</script><input value="">
```

Это XSS-уязвимость, позволяющая выполнять любой код на твоём сайте.

Вероятно, следует использовать [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) для экранирования.

Тогда [получится](https://ideone.com/CfAlIH)

```
1&quot;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('Cracked!')&lt;/script&gt;&lt;input value=&quot;
```

и оно полностью попадёт в значение:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="1&quot;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('Cracked!')&lt;/script&gt;&lt;input value=&quot;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Я как то для одного проекта писал функцию, возможно она вам пригодиться

```
function get_utm(){

// если мы не знаем реферала
if (!isset($_COOKIE['referer'])) {
    // то запоминаем его
    setcookie('referer', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], time()+30);
    $utm_referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    // А это реферер, если знаем куки и реферер вообще в наличии
}else{ $utm_referer = $_COOKIE['referer']; }

// запоминаем utm-метки
if (isset($_GET['utm_source']) && !isset($_COOKIE['utm_source'])) {
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
        if (0 === strpos($key, 'utm')) {
            setcookie($key, $val, time()+30);
            $utm .= "$key: $val\n";
        }
    }
}else{
    // Выводим все массивы в переменную $utm_result, если есть куки
    foreach ($_COOKIE as $key_utm => $val_utm) {
        if (0 === strpos($key_utm, 'utm')) {
            $utm .= "$key_utm: $val_utm\n";
        }
    }
}


// Добавляем рефера и проверяем если значение не пустое
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != '') $utm .= "utm_referer: $utm_referer\n";


// фильтруем
$utm_result = htmlspecialchars($utm, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

// Выводим весь результат
return $utm_result;
```

}

Comment: Ошибка в коде - $_SERVER['gitHTTP_REFERER']